# git difftool --cached stops working after the ninth file

Tags: git, difftool

I'm using Windows 10 and I've configured git to use Araxis Merge as the external diff tool.

When I do a `git difftool --cached` everything goes well unless I have more than 9 files staged. Once I close the window for the 9th difference, no more differences are displayed and in my console window I get:

```
error: cannot spawn ¸°s?: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at Data/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
```

The error occurs in multiple repositories, whenever there are more than 9 files staged.

If I do a `git diff --cached` everything works correctly.

```
git version 2.20.1.windows.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue is with `git difftool` at Windows 7. The 10th file cannot be compared:

```
error: cannot spawn i?: No such file or directory
fatal: external diff died, stopping at ...
```

I've found the issues reported and solved for next Git for Windows release:

[Unable to Use difftool on More than 8 Files](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2007)

[difftool cannot find file, random characters in pathname.](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1982)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please spend some time to earn a little reputation, you will then be able to comment. Do not use answers as comments.

Comment: ok, i've found the issues reported and solved for next Git for Windows release: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1982 and https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2007

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Much appreciated.

Comment: I've verified the version 2.21.0.rc0 and it works now as expected!